# Using custom route in WCF service hosted in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, routes

I have this simple service in my ASP.NET application:

```
// IBilling.cs
namespace WebApplication3.V1 {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBilling {
        [OperationContract]
        string Get();
    }
}

// Billing.svc
namespace WebApplication3.V1 {
    public class Billing : IBilling {
        public string Get() { return "Amiry"; }
    }
}
```

It's accessible (by default) through `/V1/Billing.svc` route. However, I changed the route by adding this simple line to my route-table:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(
    new ServiceRoute("api/ws/v1/billing", 
    new WebServiceHostFactory(), 
    typeof(Billing)));
```

Now, I can execute the `Get()` method and get result:

```
// it works:
http://localhost:7475/api/ws/v1/billing/get
```

BUT, the discovery address is not accessible:

```
http://localhost:7475/api/ws/v1/billing
// returns "Endpoint not found."
```

I'm pretty new to WCF services; so I have no idea where the problem could be and googling didn't help. Can you guide me to achieve the route I mentioned above please? Thanks in advance.